# Re-creating STDIN Redirection in C

Tags: c, unix, file-io

I am trying to create a C program that redirects IO. I have output done piece of cake, but input seems to be harder. Maybe I just do not quite understand it all but I am doing something like this:

```
  int redFile;

  fflush(stdin);

  myio = dup(0);

  redFile = open(rhs, O_WRONLY, 0644); 

  dup2(redFile, 0);
  close(redFile);

  // Any scanf("%s", &buf) here should read from my redFile (correct?) into some buffer, buf[64] or something

   fflush(stdin);
   dup2(myio, 0);
   close(myio);
```

So now I have some buf[64] with a string in it from the file, redFile, but how do I make this the input to a command specified by the char * lhs (set earlier in program). My entire program uses execve() to create basically a virtual shell.

I need to be able to handle some like:

input.txt:

```
test1
test2
test3

tac < input.txt > output.txt
```

output.txt

```
test3
test2
test1
```

Comment: One of `fflush(stdin);` and `fflush(stdout);` is undefined behavior - I suspect it's the output one. What if you omit it?

Comment: i do not use fflush(stdout) in this part of my program? I do not think this has anything to do with my problem

Comment: In the code you posted, there are **two** calls to `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: @H2CO3 its `stdin`, btw, that is no-flushy =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. So my suspection is actually correct, right?

Comment: @H2CO3 concerning it being wrong to flush `stdin` absolutely. it is supported in some implementations, but completely *outside* of the standard.

Comment: ok maybe fflush(stdin) is not needed or correct. I basically copied my STDOUT redirection code (which works) to here but changed the 1 to a 0..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the contents of a buffer to be the input to a process, you will need to write that data into a pipe.  Basically, you need to create a pipe and then fork.  The child will dup its input to be read from the pipe via `dup2( pfd[ 0 ], STDIN_FILENO )` and then exec, while the parent will write the data into the other side of the pipe.

Comment: so pfd[0] is what exactly?

Comment: `pfd[0]` is the read side of the pipe.  (Created with `int pfd[2]; pipe(pfd)`)

Comment: ok so I got everything set up to do dup2(myPipe[0], 0), but then I am still unsure how to get the strings from a file? Once this myPipe[0] takes over for STDIN how can I tell my program to read from the file into the pipe?

Comment: The child will not read from the file, but from stdin.  I'm confused, though: in your question you state "now I have some buf[64] with a string in it from the file".  The parent simply writes that data into the pipe, and the child will then read it from stdin (dup'd from the read side of the pipe).